# Not animation on item removed in UICollectionView with RxDataSources

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

After following the [Documentation](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) of *RxDataSources* I'm not able to make it work.

When I click on an element of the CollectionViews It is removed as my code shows but nothing happens on the views, despite there is an element less on my `sections[0].items`. I reckon that I'm doing some wrong binding the data source with the view but I'm not able to figure it out.

```
    let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<SectionOfCategoryMO>()
    private var e1cat = CatMngr.SI.getAlphabeticallyOrderedCategories(type: .e1)

    dataSource.configureCell = { ds, tv, ip, item in
        let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: ip) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.categoryName.text = item.identity.string
        cell.categoryName.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.categoryCircle.makeCircle()
        cell.categoryCircle.backgroundColor = self.categoryColors[ip.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    dataSource.animationConfiguration = AnimationConfiguration(insertAnimation: .Fade, reloadAnimation: .Fade, deleteAnimation: .Automatic)
    
    var sections = [SectionOfCategoryMO(header: "a", items: e1cat)]
    
    Observable.just(sections)
        .bindTo(myCollection.rx_itemsWithDataSource(dataSource))
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
 
    myCollection.rx_itemSelected.subscribeNext{
        sections[0].items.removeAtIndex($0.row)
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The view is loaded perfectly with all initial categories, but when I remove one of them the view is not refreshed.

Anyone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `sections` `Array` is just that, an `Array`.  `Observable.just(sections)` will not send another element just because you modified `sections` in your `rx_itemSelected` subscription.  You need to bind your data source to an `Observable` that actually sends new elements when things change.

Something like:

```
let initialData = [SectionOfCategoryMO(header: "a", items: e1cat)]
let data = Variable<SectionOfCategoryMO>(initialData)
data.asObservable()
    .bindTo(myCollection.rx_itemsWithDataSource(dataSource))
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

myCollection.rx_itemSelected.subscribeNext {
    let d = data.value
    d[0].items.removeAtIndex($0.row)
    data.value = d
}.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

However, I would recommend a more robust solution anyway.  [Use this example.](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/issues/34#issuecomment-218340829)

Comment: You were right, I didn't realize that my ´sections´ wasn't an Observable... Thank you for your quick answer!